# verify when a clipAction animation finished playing in three.js

Tags: json, animation, three.js

I’ve made an animated mesh in Blender containing two animations clips that I named *intro* and *idle*. I’ve export it with the Blender exporter in JSON. Everything works great. I can toggle which animation I want to play. My problem is that I want to play the first animation **entirely** and then switch to the second animation that I’ll set to loop.

Here is the parts of the code I use for the JSON and animation part :

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load('models/feuille(19fevrier).json',
    function (geometry, materials) {

        mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry,
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            skinning: true
        }));

        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);

        action.intro = mixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[ 0 ]);
        action.idle = mixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[ 1 ]);

        action.intro.setEffectiveWeight(1);
        action.idle.setEffectiveWeight(1);
        action.intro.enabled = true;
        action.idle.enabled = true;

        action.intro.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce, 0);


        scene.add(mesh);

        scene.traverse(function(children){
            objects.push(children);
        });

        action.intro.play();

    });
```

What I was looking for is **a function that tells me that the action is complete**, somethings like onComplete event when a clipAction finished playing. I found this response on the three.js GitHub :

```
 mesh.mixer.addEventListener('finished',function(e){

   // some code

 });
```

It seems to work but I don’t really understand the `addEventListener` in that context and neither what `function(e)` means.

There is the link of [the code I found on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7875)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`addEventListener` is part of the standard JavaScript [dispatchEvent/addEventListener concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for handling events. The three.js Animation subsystem dispatches an event whenever the animation is finished. From `AnimationAction.js`:

```
this._mixer.dispatchEvent( {
    type: 'finished', action: this,
    direction: deltaTime < 0 ? -1 : 1
} );
```

As you can see, the `e` event argument provides you with the complete `AnimationAction` object (e.action), as well as an integer representing the direction of the animation (e.direction).

Do not feel discouraged by the fact that this is undocumented behavior (three.js has grown a lot faster than Mr Doob could ever properly document). Make use of the available functionality, but do keep an eye open for possible changes in feature releases.

Comment: First and foremost thanks for reponding quickly. I understand better the `addEventListener` concept. I've tried to use the code in my script but I'm not having any result. Maybe it's a syntaxic error ? There's the code I've tried to use : 

   `mesh.mixer.addEventListener('finished',function(e.action.intro) {`

   `action.idle.play();`

   `});`

Comment: It seems like the 'finished' event handler fires before completely finishing the animation step.  I receive this event before time has completed.